Computing integer partitions subject to certain constraints
Context:
I am programming a videogame.
Background:
Let $I$ be a set of named items such that each is assigned a difficulty score, and each is tagged either as "food" or "obstacle". So each item is entirely determined by a tuple $( n, d, t )$ where $n$ (the name) is an ASCII string, $d$ (the difficulty) is a positive integer, and  $t$ (the tag) can either be 'f' (food) or 'o' (obstacle). For example, $I$ might look like
\begin{align*}
I = \{ &(\text{chicken wing}, 1, \text{f}), ( \text{egg}, 1, \text{f}), (\text{bacon}, 1, \text{f}), (\text{pizza}, 2, \text{f}), \\
       &(\text{sausage links}, 2, \text{f}), (\text{cigarette}, 2, \text{o})), (\text{meat cube}, 3, \text{f}), \\ 
       &(\text{seabass}, 3, \text{f}), ( \text{clam}, 4, \text{f}), (\text{roach}, 4, \text{o}), (\text{beer bottle}, 5, \text{o}), \\ 
       &(\text{stingray}, 10, \text{f}) \}.
\end{align*}
We can then consider the set of food difficulties $D_{\text{f}}(I)$ and of obstacles difficulties $D_{\text{o}}(I)$. As per the example above:
\begin{align*}
D_{\text{f}}(I) &= \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 10\}, \\ 
D_{\text{o}}(I) &= \{ 2, 4, 5 \}.
\end{align*}
Problem:
Given a natural $n > 0$ and a set $I$ of the form described above, find the set of integer partitions of $n$ which satisfies the following constraints:

Each part (summand) is an element of $D_\text{f}(I)$ or $D_\text{o}(I)$.
At least one part (summand) is an element of $D_\text{f}(I)$.

(The answer can be in the form of an algorithm.)

So you have a set $A$ of allowable integers, and a set $R \subseteq A$, and you want to enumerate all partitions of $n$ of the form $n=x_1+\dots+x_k$ where each $x_i \in A$, and where there exists at least one $j$ such that $x_j \in R$.  Normally, we focus on partitions where $x_1\ge x_2 \ge \cdots$.
Let $P_{A,R}(n)$ denote the set of such partitions of $n$, and $P_A(n)=P_{A,A}(n)$ the set of partitions of $n$ where we skip the requirement about $R$, and $P_{A,R}(n;t)$ the set of partitions from $P_{A,R}(n)$ whose largest part is $t$, and similarly for $P_A(n;t)$.  Then these satisfy the following recursive relation:
$$P_{A,R}(n;t) = \begin{cases}
\{t+p \mid u\le t, p \in P_A(n-t;u)\}
&\text{if } t \in R\\
\{t+p \mid u \le t, p \in P_{A,R}(n-t;u)\}
&\text{if } t \in A\setminus R\\
\emptyset &\text{if } t\notin A \text{ or } t>n
\end{cases}$$
Also
$$P_{A,R}(n) = \{p \mid t \le n, p \in P_{A,R}(n;t)\}.$$
When $t$ is an integer and $p$ is a partition (a sum of some $k$ integers), I am writing $t+p$ to denote a partition containing the following $k+1$ integers: $t$, followed by the integers in $p$.  For instance, if $t=17$ and $p$ represents $4+2+1$, then $t+p$ represents $17+4+2+1$.
These recursive relations immediately yield a recursive algorithm to enumerate all such partitions.

Can a partition be written as an ordered pair due to something along the lines of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \equiv (x_1, x_2, x_3) \equiv ( x_1 + x_2, x_3)$?

@A.B.Marnie, I'm not entirely sure whether I understood your question, but I noticed there was an error in my answer, so I've revised my answer to hopefully correct the answer.  I've also adjusted the notation and added a note on notation, which might address the point you were raising in your comment.
